# Сверстать круг

Tags: css3, вёрстка

С фишками css3 знаком плохо, как можно сделать что-то подобное? http://dropi.ru/a/rlt

Учитывая то, что внутри круга должен быть ещё и контент

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id='w'>
    <svg>
    <path d="m0,100 a100,100 0 0 1 200,00" id=path opacity=0 />
    <text id='text'>
        <textPath xlink:href=#path>
             Текст
        </textPath>
    </text>
    </svg>    
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jb9VH/1/